# Executing c++ executable from by calling by JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++

I have developed c++ program which I execute this way on terminal

```
./dtapi get_probability dc simulated_diabetes_incidence_data_new.txt  AGE 70 weight 34 height 5.5 sex 0 ds1 34
```

And the result looks like

```
{"risk_of_disease":"2.122e-314"}
```

Now I want to take input parameter from Front end, send it to executable.

What is the possible way to do this using Javascript Jquery, so that response can be received directly. ?

**Edit**

I will take user input from browser, when use press button, I will read input parameter using js/jquery and send it to back end c++ executable

Comment: you want to do this from a browser via a server?

Comment: I will take user input from browser, when user press button, I will read input parameter using js/jquery and send it to back end c++ executable @JaromandaX

Comment: you need [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - I take it you've made the appropriate configuration to your server to execute the dtapi command when appropriate?

Comment: also realize that there could be big security implications if you are allowing arbitrary input from users which outputs to a terminal command.  For instance a user could possibly craft an input value that executes additional commands on your server which you are not intending.  This kind of thing is hard to get right from a security standpoint.

Comment: @Aliester - as far as I can make out he's only asking about frontend, so lets hope he has the back end sorted out and functioning correctly and securely

Comment: @JaromandaX Agreed just wanted to highlight that getting the value to the server to use in a terminal command is not all he should be keeping in mind.  If that value is not properly validated it could open up his server to attack.  Additionally the permissions that command is ran under needs to be as restrictive as possible.

Comment: @Aliester: Thanks you very much. I knew this, but forgot at this moment. I will take care of it. I appreciate your help to complete this task before I get into security implementation.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yeah, Ajax can help, but how it can be done that I could not find. Any reference link or basic example will be much helpful.

Comment: that documentation I linked to has all the examples you should need for the front end code - did you also need help with how to get your http server to execute that command when appropriate?

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yeah, that will also help me

Comment: well you'll have to supply **details** of your server environment if you want help setting that up.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple actually. Assume we have an adder program made in C++ that add the numbers passed as arguments like this:

```
./adder 2 3 6
{"risk_of_disease":"11"}
```

If we use a server side language like PHP, then we can have a simple form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" value="<?php echo $num1; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="num2" value="<?php echo $num2; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="num3" value="<?php echo $num3; ?>">
    <button>Submit and run executable adder</button>
</form>
```

And the PHP code like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['num1']) &&
   isset($_POST['num2']) &&
   isset($_POST['num3']))
{
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
    $num3 = $_POST['num3'];
    $exec_cmd = "../bin/adder {$num1} {$num2} {$num3}";
    $json_result = shell_exec($exec_cmd);
} else {
    $num1 = 0;
    $num2 = 0;
    $num3 = 0;
}
```

- The location of the executable is on `'../bin/'` directory.
- The executable must have same ownership as the PHP user executing the
  script page (ex.: `chown web35:client3 ./adder`).
- PHP should not have `shell_exec` in the `disable_functions` for the specific pool/user, or else it won't be able the run the program.

A complete example:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['num1']) &&
   isset($_POST['num2']) &&
   isset($_POST['num3']))
{
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
    $num3 = $_POST['num3'];
    $exec_cmd = "../bin/adder {$num1} {$num2} {$num3}";
    $json_result = shell_exec($exec_cmd);
} else {
    $num1 = 0;
    $num2 = 0;
    $num3 = 0;
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" value="<?php echo $num1; ?>" size="5">
    <input type="text" name="num2" value="<?php echo $num2; ?>" size="5">
    <input type="text" name="num3" value="<?php echo $num3; ?>" size="5">
    <button>Submit and run adder</button>
</form>

<?php if(isset($json_result)): ?>
<h3>JSON result from executable</h3>
<pre><?php echo $json_result; ?></pre>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

**EDIT**

For a jQuery ajax call, just create a php file with the following code:

**exerun.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['num1']) &&
   isset($_POST['num2']) &&
   isset($_POST['num3']))
{
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
    $num3 = $_POST['num3'];
    $exec_cmd = "../bin/adder {$num1} {$num2} {$num3}";
    die(shell_exec($exec_cmd));
} else {
    die('{"risk_of_disease":"0"}');
}
```

And then have your simplejQuery ajax call liek this:

```
<form method="post" action="exerun.php">
    <input type="text" name="num1" value="0" size="5">
    <input type="text" name="num2" value="0" size="5">
    <input type="text" name="num3" value="0" size="5">
    <button type="submit">Submit and run adder</button>
</form>

<h3>JSON result from executable</h3>
<textarea id="result" cols="30"></textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to run an AJAX call without a submit form, then you can pass the arguments directly as an object and have the url manually assigned like this:

```
<button id="execall">Run AXAJ remote exec</button>

<h3>JSON result from executable</h3>
<textarea id="result" cols="30"></textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#execall').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'exerun.php',
            data: {
                'num1': 10,
                'num2': 20,
                'num3': 30
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Apart from using form submit methods, can you pleas suggest alternate method where I can call the php script during ajax call only. Without using form

Comment: You can make a direct AJAX call to the PHP exec script. See my updated answer.